# How to center zoom controls in the WebView

Tags: android, webview

I've learnt today, that it's no problem to enable zoom controls in a webview.

```
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

That is nice.

But they are not in center of the screen. Is it possible to change their position?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can change the position of the built-in zoom controls for a WebView (if it is anything like the MapView, you can't), but you will be able to position a ZoomControls widget: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ZoomControls.html